# Guide to understand data from Prime sense sensor?

Tags: c++, kinect, openni, primesense

I looking for sources to understand the data from Prime sense sensor. My first goal will be detecting if there is a object in front of the sensor. How to I know that from data? I can not find a guide for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for documentation on the SDKs, not the sensor itself.

- [Microsoft Kinect SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855347.aspx), on MSDN
- [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- [OpenNI](http://www.openni.org/)

These are what provide you the information you can parse to determine if something is in front of the camera and if it is a person.

If you just wanting to use the device as a camera, without depth and skeleton analysis, then you can use one of the many image processing libraries.